# Immutable strings in java

Tags: java, string, immutability

how come this prints true:

```
String sOne = new String();
sOne = "one";
String sTwo = new String();
sTwo = "one";
System.out.println(sOne == sTwo ? "true": "false");
```

but this prints false:

```
String sOne = new String("one");
String sTwo = new String("one");
System.out.println(sOne == sTwo ? "true": "false");
```

Shouldn't they both print false?... I understand that strings are immutable and all but I do not understand why NOT initializing with the constructor causes the different output

Answer (score 7):

Because the literal `"one"` refers to the *same String object* everywhere it appears; string literals are always interned.  The two variables in the first example will reference the same object.

In the second case, you force construction of a *new* string object in the two assignments, and so the strings are equal but are different instances; the two variables reference equivalent but *different* objects.

The expression `sOne.equals(sTwo)` should return true in both examples, as it will perform an equality test on the string content.

Comment: It's not just plain literals that are interned -- it's any constant string expression, which means a string literal _or_ the concatenation (using `+`) of two (or more) string literals. See [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) and [JSL 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

Answer (score 1):

In Java if you do a comparison like in C x == y the objects (i.e. pointers) are compared, but not their content. That's why you need to use obj.equals(other_obj) to make sure that they are functionally the same objects. It's similar like comparing the pointer in C. If the pointer is the same, your are looking at the same object. if the pointers are different, the two objects can still have the same values, but are different objects.

```
    String v1 = "Test";
    String v2 = v1;

    if(v1 == v2)
        System.out.println("1true");

    v2 = "Test"; // referencing the same object
    if(v1 == v2)
        System.out.println("2true");
    if(v1.equals(v2))
        System.out.println("3true");

    v2 = new String("Test");  // new object/pointer same content
    if(v1 == v2)
        System.out.println("4true");
    if(v1.equals(v2))
        System.out.println("5true");
```

Output:

```
1true
2true
3true
5true
```